# Sourcing Historical Wind data?

Tags: data, web-service, weather

I'm looking for a service that provides hourly historical data for 24h and back. I am currently interfacing openweathermap.org but had to find out that not all stations provide this feature.

Are there any other free services that provide this data?

Comment: The lack of data might be due to the weather station itself not capturing the information, in which case it won't be available from any source. Looking through NOAA's [land-based datasets](http://www.ncdc.noaa.gov/data-access/land-based-station-data/land-based-datasets) (probably ASOS or AWOS) is a possible source.

Comment: Thanks for the NOAA link - but that only includes US, no?

Comment: Yes, if you're interested in global (or indeed anywhere non-US) then it won't work :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try finding a station on Wunderground that fits your needs and then use their API to get what you want.

Comment: Ha, underground looks useful but costs money unfortunately. Good call though, I'll look into it :)

Comment: They have free accounts, how many calls do you need per day?

Comment: Yes, I believe i should be good with the free quota, I'm only worried with 10 / minute. Anywho, I'll give it a shot :)